# jQuery 1.6, changed its .val() behavior?

Tags: jquery, html-select

In jQuery 1.6, it seems to me that the `.val()` function has been changed since jQuery 1.5.2.

When I call it on a select's option to get a value, now I get the text.
For example:

```
<option value="1">john</option>
```

When I call:

```
$('select').val();
```

with jQuery 1.5.2 I get **1** while with jQuery 1.6 I get **john**

I know they changed behavior of `.attr()` and introduced `.prop()`, but at [this link](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/) I'm not able to find anything about `.val()`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KFDWm/3/) is an example that shows this difference and what I've tried so far to get the option's value. Switch from jQuery 1.6 to jQuery 1.5.2 to see.

How do I get an option's **value** with jQuery 1.6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in v1.6 where `val('asdf')` no longer sets the value: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9071 This bug has been fixed in v1.6.1.

Also, despite what others have said, it's totally okay to use val() to set the value---actually, according to the jQuery team it's preferred over using `attr('value', 'asdf')`.

Answer (score 8):

Your mistake in your jsfiddle example is to use `val` to *create* the value, for this you should rather use `attr('value', id)`. Then `val()` still works as expected, the same as in previous versions, and you can get the `option` value with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/KFDWm/5/

Comment: ok this is clear thanks, but why .val(), as setter, no longer works in jQuery 1.6?

Comment: As I understand it, `val()` should ideally be used once the element has already been created. The first time round, it's important to set `value` specifically, as you normally would when creating the element in HTML. I suspect this is because `val()` checks the value of the `value` attribute when getting, but it doesn't create it if it doesn't already exists. If that makes sense. If anyone else has a better explanation, I'd also love to hear it.

Comment: seems reasonable, maybe some where in the docs this is also written but i just missed it. Thanks again

Comment: Turned out this was an active bug in jQuery at that stage, which I mistakenly assumed to be part of the new version. Refer to the accepted answer!